# WS2812 Stair lighting - not all LEDS lighting up

Tags: programming

I'm doing a Arduino based stair light project and have a little problem with the code. I have used [Simon Jowett's code from the instructable website](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-bling-up-a-boring-staircase/) which after a couple of tweaks works perfect. Apart from the final section, the waterfall effect. The original project used 117 WS2812 LED's I'm using 188. When the white LED's trigger running up or down the stairs they work fine on all 188, the breathe LED's light up on the first and last LED too. But the waterfall effect stops at LED 117. Can anyone see if there is somewhere else that I need to change the amount of LED's in the code apart from here Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(***188***, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);? Thanks

```
// "Bling" up your Staircase By Simon Jowett November 2014
// Thanks to the Neopxel Library by Adafruit


#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
//#define LDRSensor 1
#define PIN 3

// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = Arduino pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(188, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// IMPORTANT: To reduce NeoPixel burnout risk, add 1000 uF capacitor across
// pixel power leads, add 300 - 500 Ohm resistor on first pixel's data input
// and minimize distance between Arduino and first pixel.  Avoid connecting
// on a live circuit...if you must, connect GND first.

// Set up Variables
 unsigned long timeOut=60000; // timestamp to remember when the PIR was triggered.
 int downUp = 0;              // variable to rememer the direction of travel up or down the stairs
 int alarmPinTop = 5;        // PIR at the top of the stairs
 int alarmPinBottom =7;      // PIR at the bottom of the stairs
 int alarmValueTop = LOW;    // Variable to hold the PIR status
 int alarmValueBottom = LOW; // Variable to hold the PIR status
 int ledPin = 13;           // LED on the arduino board flashes when PIR activated
 int LDRSensor = A0;        // Light dependant resistor
 int LDRValue = 0;          // Variable to hold the LDR value
 int colourArray[350];      // An array to hold RGB values
 int change = 1;            // used in 'breathing' the LED's
 int breathe = 0;           // used in 'breathing' the LED's


void setup() {
   strip.begin();
   strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
   Serial.begin (9600);  // only requred for debugging
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // initilise the onboard pin 13 LED as an indicator
   pinMode(alarmPinTop, INPUT_PULLUP);     // for PIR at top of stairs initialise the input pin and use the internal restistor
   pinMode(alarmPinBottom, INPUT_PULLUP);  // for PIR at bottom of stairs initialise the input pin and use the internal restistor
   delay (100); // it takes the sensor 2 seconds to scan the area around it before it can 
   //detect infrared presence.
   for (int i=0 ;i < 350; i++)  { // initilise the colourArray to zero
   colourArray[i]=0; 
   } 
}

void loop() {

  LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);
  Serial.println(LDRValue);

  if (timeOut+57000 < millis()) {        // idle state - 'breathe' the top and bottom LED to show program is looping

     breathe = breathe + change;
     strip.setPixelColor(0,0,0,breathe);
     strip.setPixelColor(187,0,0,breathe);
     strip.show();
     if (breathe == 100 || breathe == 0) change = -change;      // breathe the LED from 0 = off to 100 = fairly bright
     if (breathe == 100 || breathe == 0) delay (300);           // Pause at beginning and end of each breath
     delay(25); 
  }

  if (LDRValue > 1010) {        // only switch on LED's at night when LDR senses low light conditions - you may have to change the number for your circumstances!

    alarmValueTop = digitalRead(alarmPinTop);        // Constantly poll the PIR at the top of the stairs
    alarmValueBottom = digitalRead(alarmPinBottom);  // Constantly poll the PIR at the bottom of the stairs

    if (alarmValueTop == HIGH && downUp != 2)  {      // the 2nd term allows timeOut to be contantly reset if one lingers at the top of the stairs before decending but will not allow the bottom PIR to reset timeOut as you decend past it.
      timeOut=millis();  // Timestamp when the PIR is triggered.  The LED cycle wil then start.
      downUp = 1;
      topdown();         // lights up the strip from top down
    }

    if (alarmValueBottom == HIGH && downUp != 1)  {    // the 2nd term allows timeOut to be contantly reset if one lingers at the bottom of the stairs before decending but will not allow the top PIR to reset timeOut as you decend past it.
      timeOut=millis();    // Timestamp when the PIR is triggered.  The LED cycle wil then start.
      downUp = 2;
      bottomup();         // lights up the strip from bottom up
    }
    if (timeOut+10000 < millis() && timeOut+15000 < millis()) {    //switch off LED's in the direction of travel.
       if (downUp == 1) {
          colourWipeDown(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // Off
       }
       if (downUp == 2)  {
        colourWipeUp(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);   // Off
       }
      downUp = 0;
      //   for (int i=0 ;i < 350; i++)  {          // Depending on your preference you may want to include this loop to clear out the colourArray
      //    colourArray[i]=0; 
      // }
    }

    if (timeOut+15000 < millis() && timeOut+54999 > millis()) waterfall();    // Waterfall effect to play between these times after a PIR trigger.

    if (timeOut+55000 < millis() && timeOut+56999 > millis()) fade();   // Fade/switch off LED's
  }
}

 void topdown() {
    Serial.println ("detected top");                // Helpful debug message
    colourWipeDown(strip.Color(50, 50, 30), 10);    // Warm White
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {                        // Helpful debug indication flashes led on Arduino board twice
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
 }

 void bottomup() {
    Serial.println ("detected bottom");          // Helpful debug message
    colourWipeUp(strip.Color(50, 50, 30), 10);   // Warm White
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {                     // Helpful debug indication flashes led on Arduino board twice
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
  }

 // Fill the dots one after the other with a color
 void colourWipeDown(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
   for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  }
 }

 // Fill the dots one after the other with a color
 void colourWipeUp(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
   for(uint16_t i=strip.numPixels(); i < -1; i--) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  }
 }

 // Play the Waterfall effect
 void waterfall(){
    for(int i= 347; i>-1; i--) {            // Shift the RGB colours down in the colourArray[] 
        colourArray[i+3]=colourArray[i];
        }
      colourArray[0] = random(0,20);        // Genearate the red component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs
      colourArray[1] = random(0,40);        // Genearate the green component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs
      colourArray[2] = random(10,70);       // Genearate the blue component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs

      for (int k=0; k<351; k=k+3)   {       // Set and send the colours to the strip
       uint32_t c = strip.Color(colourArray[k],colourArray[k+1],colourArray[k+2]);
       strip.setPixelColor(((k+3)/3)-1,c);
       }

      strip.show();      // and display the result
      delay(35);         // delay to simulate running water 
 }

 // Play the LED fade out
 void fade(){
 for (int j = 0; j <70; j++) {
   for(int i=350; i>-1; i--) {
     colourArray[i]=colourArray[i]-1;      // reduce intensity of light by 1
     if (colourArray[i] <= 0 ) colourArray[i] = 0;
   }
   for (int k=0; k<351; k=k+3)   {
     uint32_t c = strip.Color(colourArray[k],colourArray[k+1],colourArray[k+2]);
     strip.setPixelColor(((k+3)/3)-1,c);
   }
  strip.show();
  delay(60);
  }
 breathe = 0;
 change = 1; 
 }
```

Comment: Added a link to the Instructable website.  Please comment if not correct.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you use an int array for the LED color values, instead of the `CRGB` typed array, that is used in all the NeoPixel examples?

Answer (score 1):

This line in the code:

```
 int colourArray[350];      // An array to hold RGB values
```

...contains 3 values for each LED.  But 350 / 3 is 116.67.  This value should likely have been 117 * 3 = 351 for the original code.  And for the posted code using 188 LEDs this likely should be 188 * 3 = 546.

This same problem of indexing into the colourArray repeats several more times in the code where the array is cleared out, assigned random values and used to control the LEDs.  Normally, well written code uses "#define" directive to set such values once at the beginning of the code allowing the compiler to make adjustments when compiling / uploading the Arduino sketch.

The ["#define" used for Arduino sketches](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/further-syntax/define/) is the same as used in C programming.  (As Arduino sketches are actually C programs.) Normally, defines are found at the top of a file.  Defines are a way of substituting an meaningful name for something a bit hard to understand at first.  We can even use a bit of math to keep errors down as the compiler will solve it for us before uploading the code:

```
#define LED_NUMBER_OF (3*188)
```

Later in the code we can use the define:

```
int colourArray[LED_NUMBER_OF];      // An array to hold RGB values
```

Still later in the code we can use the define again:

```
for (int i=0 ;i < LED_NUMBER_OF; i++)  { // initilise the colourArray to zero
  colourArray[i]=0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks st2000, I've adjusted the code as you suggested will I need to do the same for the waterfall section?

Comment: Probably.  The quick (and maybe good enough) approach is to search for the number 350 and decide if what you want can be achieved by substituting 546 or the define LED_NUMBER_OF of you went that route.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the edited code but now the LED's won't work at all?? I'm sure its something I've done wrong.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 3

#define LED_NUMBER_OF (3*188)

// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = Arduino pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not v2)
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(188, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

// IMPORTANT: To reduce NeoPixel burnout risk, add 1000 uF capacitor across
// pixel power leads, add 300 - 500 Ohm resistor on first pixel's data input
// and minimize distance between Arduino and first pixel.  Avoid connecting
// on a live circuit...if you must, connect GND first.

// Set up Variables
 unsigned long timeOut=60000; // timestamp to remember when the PIR was triggered.
 int downUp = 0;              // variable to rememer the direction of travel up or down the stairs
 int alarmPinTop = 5;        // PIR at the top of the stairs
 int alarmPinBottom =7;      // PIR at the bottom of the stairs
 int alarmValueTop = LOW;    // Variable to hold the PIR status
 int alarmValueBottom = LOW; // Variable to hold the PIR status
 int ledPin = 13;           // LED on the arduino board flashes when PIR activated
 int LDRSensor = A0;        // Light dependant resistor
 int LDRValue = 0;          // Variable to hold the LDR value
 int colourArray[LED_NUMBER_OF];      // An array to hold RGB values
 int change = 1;            // used in 'breathing' the LED's
 int breathe = 0;           // used in 'breathing' the LED's


void setup() {
   strip.begin();
   strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
   Serial.begin (9600);  // only requred for debugging
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // initilise the onboard pin 13 LED as an indicator
   pinMode(alarmPinTop, INPUT_PULLUP);     // for PIR at top of stairs initialise the input pin and use the internal restistor
   pinMode(alarmPinBottom, INPUT_PULLUP);  // for PIR at bottom of stairs initialise the input pin and use the internal restistor
   delay (100); // it takes the sensor 2 seconds to scan the area around it before it can 
   //detect infrared presence.
   for (int i=0 ;i < LED_NUMBER_OF; i++)  { // initilise the colourArray to zero
   colourArray[i]=0; 
   } 
}

void loop() {

  LDRValue = analogRead(LDRSensor);
  Serial.println(LDRValue);

  if (timeOut+57000 < millis()) {        // idle state - 'breathe' the top and bottom LED to show program is looping

     breathe = breathe + change;
     strip.setPixelColor(0,0,0,breathe);
     strip.setPixelColor(187,0,0,breathe);
     strip.show();
     if (breathe == 100 || breathe == 0) change = -change;      // breathe the LED from 0 = off to 100 = fairly bright
     if (breathe == 100 || breathe == 0) delay (300);           // Pause at beginning and end of each breath
     delay(25); 
  }

  if (LDRValue > 1010) {        // only switch on LED's at night when LDR senses low light conditions - you may have to change the number for your circumstances!

    alarmValueTop = digitalRead(alarmPinTop);        // Constantly poll the PIR at the top of the stairs
    alarmValueBottom = digitalRead(alarmPinBottom);  // Constantly poll the PIR at the bottom of the stairs

    if (alarmValueTop == HIGH && downUp != 2)  {      // the 2nd term allows timeOut to be contantly reset if one lingers at the top of the stairs before decending but will not allow the bottom PIR to reset timeOut as you decend past it.
      timeOut=millis();  // Timestamp when the PIR is triggered.  The LED cycle wil then start.
      downUp = 1;
      topdown();         // lights up the strip from top down
    }

    if (alarmValueBottom == HIGH && downUp != 1)  {    // the 2nd term allows timeOut to be contantly reset if one lingers at the bottom of the stairs before decending but will not allow the top PIR to reset timeOut as you decend past it.
      timeOut=millis();    // Timestamp when the PIR is triggered.  The LED cycle wil then start.
      downUp = 2;
      bottomup();         // lights up the strip from bottom up
    }
    if (timeOut+10000 < millis() && timeOut+15000 < millis()) {    //switch off LED's in the direction of travel.
       if (downUp == 1) {
          colourWipeDown(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50); // Off
       }
       if (downUp == 2)  {
        colourWipeUp(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 50);   // Off
       }
      downUp = 0;
      //   for (int i=0 ;i < 350; i++)  {          // Depending on your preference you may want to include this loop to clear out the colourArray
      //    colourArray[i]=0; 
      // }
    }

    if (timeOut+15000 < millis() && timeOut+54999 > millis()) waterfall();    // Waterfall effect to play between these times after a PIR trigger.

    if (timeOut+55000 < millis() && timeOut+56999 > millis()) fade();   // Fade/switch off LED's
  }
}

 void topdown() {
    Serial.println ("detected top");                // Helpful debug message
    colourWipeDown(strip.Color(50, 50, 30), 10);    // Warm White
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {                        // Helpful debug indication flashes led on Arduino board twice
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
 }

 void bottomup() {
    Serial.println ("detected bottom");          // Helpful debug message
    colourWipeUp(strip.Color(50, 50, 30), 10);   // Warm White
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {                     // Helpful debug indication flashes led on Arduino board twice
      digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
  }

 // Fill the dots one after the other with a color
 void colourWipeDown(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
   for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  }
 }

 // Fill the dots one after the other with a color
 void colourWipeUp(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
   for(uint16_t i=strip.numPixels(); i < -1; i--) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  }
 }

 // Play the Waterfall effect
 void waterfall(){
    for(int i= 350; i>-1; i--) {            // Shift the RGB colours down in the colourArray[] 
        colourArray[i+3]=colourArray[i];
        }
      colourArray[0] = random(0,20);        // Genearate the red component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs
      colourArray[1] = random(0,40);        // Genearate the green component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs
      colourArray[2] = random(10,70);       // Genearate the blue component of the 1st LED at the top of the stairs

      for (int k=0; k<350; k=k+3)   {       // Set and send the colours to the strip
       uint32_t c = strip.Color(colourArray[k],colourArray[k+1],colourArray[k+2]);
       strip.setPixelColor(((k+3)/3)-1,c);
       }

      strip.show();      // and display the result
      delay(35);         // delay to simulate running water 
 }

 // Play the LED fade out
 void fade(){
 for (int j = 0; j <70; j++) {
   for(int i=350; i>-1; i--) {
     colourArray[i]=colourArray[i]-1;      // reduce intensity of light by 1
     if (colourArray[i] <= 0 ) colourArray[i] = 0;
   }
   for (int k=0; k<351; k=k+3)   {
     uint32_t c = strip.Color(colourArray[k],colourArray[k+1],colourArray[k+2]);
     strip.setPixelColor(((k+3)/3)-1,c);
   }
  strip.show();
  delay(60);
  }
 breathe = 0;
 change = 1; 
 }
~~~~~~
```

Comment: Likely you needed to use the LED_NUMBER_OF define where ever you access the colourArray array.  I see you changed 350 to 351 in some places.  Perhaps if you tried using  LED_NUMBER_OF instead of 351.  Also, note there is one line of code where you need to use (LED_NUMBER_OF - 3) because you add 3 to the index of the FOR loop inside the loop.  And it is bad to access locations past the end of any array!

Comment: Try not to re-post your question as an answer. Remember that stack exchange / stack overflow web sites are trying to become a list of searchable questions and answers. This will make it really confusing for people with similar issues.

Comment: if your program is working can you do 2 things?  1. Delete this answer and if you need to edit your question should you wish to add additional information to make the question better.  2. If an answer is correct (that is, if the answer help fix the issue in the question), please mark it correct so that others can see what worked for you.  Thanks.